# Changing display and opacity with CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following button :

HTML :

```
<button id='foo' style='display: none; opacity: 0'>Foo</button>
```

CSS :

```
    #foo {
      transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    }
```

JS :

```
  $('#foo').css('display', '');
  $('#foo').css('opacity', '');
```

It's working in a sense, the button does appear, but without the animation.
So I am not sure what's the issue here.
Does anyone have any idea ?

Also, I don't want suggestions mentioning visibility because that's not the point here. Thanks !

Comment: Try transitioning to `opacity:1` instead of *empty string*.

Comment: use opacity instead of display. With using these together you cannot achieve what you want

Comment: @PraveenKumar This is *not* a duplicate of that question. The OP wants to transition opacity, not display.

Comment: @Juhana It is also answered in that question. But anyways, if you feel it should be reopened. Yea, fine. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar The problem in this question is that the OP is changing CSS properties manually which doesn't trigger transitions. There's no answer to that in the other question.

Comment: There is no transition on the display. The display switch from none to block, then afterwards the opacity changes and the transition is on the opacity.

Comment: @Juhana As you say boss.

Comment: @Juhana changing CSS properties directly on the element does trigger transitions: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/22wwur61/1/. I agree it's not great practice though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate setting the `display` property from setting the properties involved in the animation. If you set them in one round the animations won't run (the problem is with `display: none`). One way is to do a `setTimeout`.

Also, my suggestion is to never change style properties from JS, always manipulate classes for better separation. Something like this will do:

```js
var $foo = $('#foo').addClass('display');
 
setTimeout(function () {
  $foo.addClass('show');
});
```

```css
#foo {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

#foo.display {
  display: inline-block;
}

#foo.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='foo'>Foo</button>
```

Comment: Thanks sir, exactly what I wanted !

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue that's stopping your example from working is because you're changing the `display` state of the element. Remove the `display` setting and your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/pcp2x53m/

That being said there are a couple of issues. Firstly, don't set a property to `''`. There are default values which they should be set to instead. Secondly, use classes as it is better practice.

If you require the element to be set to `display: none` by default then you need to wait for the element to be set to `display: block` before you set its opacity and allow the transition to begin.

Here's a fully working example:

```js
$('#foo').show(0, function() {
    $(this).addClass('fade-in');
});
```

```css
#foo {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
#foo.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="foo">Foo</button>
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/jvfekhfo/2/)

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't answer the question at all. First of all, the example is indeed very dumb, so there is no point saying so.
Second, the purpose here is to switch the display and then switch the opacity and have the animation working once the opacity is changing after the display has already changed. So your answer doesn't answer that. I mean, "what you want to do is not feasible" may be the right answer. But not yours sorry.

Comment: `First of all, the example is indeed very dumb, so there is no point saying so.` Where did I say the example was dumb?

Comment: Sorry but at this point it's basically playing the grammar nazi, and being surprised when people ask you not to do so ...