# css transition not working for display: none

Tags: html, css

Can't figure out why does transition not working

So, the idea is that block with some text should be visible on :hover.
It's working as exepect for the non-hover state (hiding the text thought rgba)

I tried both all and display properties. Also I tried adding transitions to all elements, like h3 and p.

Please visit 
https://jsfiddle.net/dyrc522f/

```
<div class="photo photo2">Some title
                <div class="photobl photobl2">
                    <h3>Some title</h3>
                    <p>text</p>
                </div> 
            </div>
```

css

```
.photo{
    width: 244px;
    height: 219px;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 180px;
    -webkit-transition:all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition:all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition:all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;

  background-color: tomato;/**/
    }
.photo:hover{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.photo:hover .photobl{
    display: block;
}
.photobl{
    display: none;
    width: 244px;
    height: 399px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) url('../images/logomin.png') center 40px no-repeat;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: display .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: display .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: display .4s ease;
    transition: display .4s ease;
    }
.photobl h3{
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #ffcc00;
    padding-top: 181px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
.photobl p{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.3;
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use transition for opacity but not display. A great, and complete, answer here: [CSS3 transition doesn't work with display property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103006/css3-transition-doesnt-work-with-display-property)

Comment: That's right. Im stupid :) Thank for help!

Comment: No worries Sergey. You are not stupid at all. Took me some headdesks before I realised what was wrong on this one. :)