# Css transition from display none to display block, navigation with subnav

Tags: html, css

This is what I have [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vour8ad9/)

```css
nav.main ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(92, 91, 87, 0.9);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
            transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
}

nav.main ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">Lorem</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sit</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Amet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Why is there no transition? If I set

```
nav.main ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0; /* changed this line */
}
```

Then the "subnav" will never appear (of course ) but why does the transition on the opacity not trigger? How to get the transition working?

Comment: Fade transition works for me if you remove the display properties: https://jsfiddle.net/LgvhLxya/

Comment: @JamesWaddington Thats what I've been saying.

Comment: Why don't you do it with Jquery show and hide? Then, you can do your animation.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As you know the `display` property cannot be animated BUT just by having it in your CSS it overrides the `visibility` and `opacity` transitions.

The solution...just removed the `display` properties.

```css
nav.main ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(92, 91, 87, 0.9);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
  transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
}
nav.main ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Lorem</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Ipsum</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Dolor</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Sit</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Amet</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes, but that ul will take up the space in the dom this way.

Comment: Shouldn't matter because you are using absolute positioning which removed the element from normal document flow. Here is another post similar to your's ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103006/css3-transition-doesnt-work-with-display-property. Remove both `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`.

Comment: Yes but this causes weird clickable but invisible links. It may interrupt your other elements if they're on the same space.

Comment: Also using keyboard navigation is disrupted as tabbing around will select invisible links (and thus have no visible effect to the user – confusing to say the least).

Comment: @Vcasso  for the occupied space problem, in this solution you can add max-height property and define it in the transition property, when hover out just set the max-height 0 else set to some high value and then it will not occupy the space.

Answer (score 84):

Generally when people are trying to animate `display: none` what they really want is:

1. Fade content in, and
2. Have the item not take up space in the document when hidden

Most popular answers use `visibility`, which can only achieve the first goal, but luckily it's just as easy to achieve both by using `position`.

Since `position: absolute` removes the element from typing document flow spacing, you can toggle between `position: absolute` and `position: static` (global default), combined with `opacity`. See the below example.

```css
.content-page {
  position:absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.content-page.active {
  position: static;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: What if I'm using `display: flex` on a parent element to have a vertically centered content (to be faded out/in)? `position: absolute` breaks it then.

Comment: There are other ways to vertically center, such as using line height, view height, or jquery/javascript. Or can you create childen within your flex displayed parent?

Comment: What do you suggest if I can create children?

Comment: [Animating `position`](https://codepen.io/dandv/pen/oQgEME) doesn't work on iOS Safari :-/

Comment: Personally I like to avoid JS timers. So fading opacity and then setting display:none; would be nice.

Comment: Who says that absolute positioned elements do not take up space? https://jsfiddle.net/centurianii/nwvyf749/

Comment: I needed this! Thank you!

Comment: But with this solution, I am still able to modify the element with opacity = 0. For example, if this was a selectbox, I could potentially select an option. Can I somehow disable this?

Comment: This answer has helped me, thanks a lot @AiDev

Answer (score 54):

You can do this with animation-keyframe rather than transition. Change your hover declaration and add the animation keyframe, you might also need to add browser prefixes for -moz- and -webkit-. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes for more detailed info.

```css
nav.main ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(92, 91, 87, 0.9);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
            transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
}

nav.main ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fade 1s;
}

@keyframes fade {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="main">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">Lorem</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sit</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Amet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is an update on your fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/orax9d9u/1/

Comment: @Drenai: where is `visibility: hidden` used?

Comment: @DanDascalescu I've updated the answer to include the base styles

Comment: That's the only viable answer! Playing with position `absolute` or `static` is wrong as someone else suggested! https://jsfiddle.net/centurianii/nwvyf749/

Comment: In case you use this solution keep in mind that it works only on fade in. It won't work for fade out because display:none is applied immediately.