# How to display a div when hovering over an image using CSS/HTML + Transitions?

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

I'm trying to achieve two things I can't figure out:
1) How to display a div when I hover over an image, ideally with a transition effect.
2) How to make the div stay up when the user shifts the mouse from the image to the div itself.

Here's my code so far; it has no transition effect and unless the div is directly next to the image, it doesn't stay up when I mouse over to it.

```
<style>
#Picture {
position: fixed; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; margin: auto;
width: 375px;
height: 375px;
}

#content {
display: none;
position: fixed; left: -800px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; margin: auto;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-color: #7377a8;
}

#Picture:hover + #content {display: block;}

#content:hover {display:block;}
</style>
<body>
<img src="" alt="Picture" id="Picture" />
<div id="Content">
Something goes here
</div>
</body>
```

P.S. I am sorry if I formatted anything incorrectly; I am brand new to the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Css transition from display none to display block, navigation with subnav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772442/css-transition-from-display-none-to-display-block-navigation-with-subnav)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hover` effect is not mobile-friendly (though there are more and more 'hover-sensitive' devices).
To accomodate most devices I often use both `:hover` and `:focus` to 'dropdown' things. However, this 
requires 'focusable' elements, for which I usually use the `<a>`nchor tag.

But first: The point in your code is consistency as you are mix-matching lowercase and uppercase in `#content` and `id="Content"`. That is why it does not work anyway.

Answering your questions:

1) make upper/lowercase consistent!

2) To create a hover with persistency, trigger the display of 'content' with a focusable 'trigger' element

On hover/click the outer `<a>` stays focused and therefore its sibling `#content` visible.
On hover `.shorttext` its sibling `.longtext` will show.

On click `.shorttext` (actually anywhere in `#content`) the content box will close again as the outer `<a>` loses focus again.

FYI-1, attribute `display` is not animatable, so you will need an alternative when you need a transition on some element. In this case `opacity` going from 0 to 1 is used (optionally combined with `width` and `height`, from 0 to 300px).

FYI-2, using `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead of `href="#"` will prevent browers from adding an entry in their history log each click.

FYI-3 final, use CSS classes by default, these are generic making it a lot easier to copy the same behaviour in your HTML, without repeating CSS each time. IDs are specific and require you to copy equal CSS over and over.

```css
a {
  color: currentColor;
  text-decoration: none
}

.picture {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 375px;
  height: 375px;
}

.content {
  /*  display: none;  remove */
  opacity: 0; /* add */
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out; /* add */
  position: fixed;
  left: -800px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0; /* [OPTIONAL] modify from 300px */
  height: 0; /* ditto */
  background-color: #7377a8;
}

.trigger:hover+.content,
.trigger:focus+.content {
  /* add, for persistent display of content. click elsewhere to close again */
  /*  display: block; remove */
  opacity: 1; /* add */
  width: 300px; /* [OPTIONAL] add, see above */
  height: 300px;
}

.shorttext { /* eye-candy only */
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center
}

.longtext {
  display: none
}

.shorttext:hover+.longtext {
  display: block;
}

/* little debug helper */

[outlines="1"] * {
  outline: 1px dashed purple
}
```

```html
<body outlines="0">
<a class="trigger" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300?random=1" alt="Picture" class="picture" /></a>
<div class="content">
    <h3 class="shorttext">short intro text, hover me</h3>

    <p class="longtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et
        deleniti copiosae.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually pretty working. Your problem is that picture and div are not next to each other. Just move them side by side and it'll be fine.

Your div's id was **Content** and in CSS it was **content**. In some browsers IDs are case sensitive so that was maybe another problem.

I used opacity instead of display to make transition working.

Here's my code:

```css
#picture {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#content {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #7377a8;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

#picture:hover + #content {
    opacity: 1;
}

#content:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="" alt="Picture" id="picture" />
<div id="content">
    Something goes here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple trick would be to put both the **image** and **content** inside of a **div**.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="img.jpg" alt="image" class="container__img">
  <p class="container__content">
    Something goes here
  </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container__img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.container_content {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .5s;
}
.container:hover > .container__content {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

change **display** property for the *content* if you dont want space to be taken before it displays.
ask if something is unclear.