# Flickering Issue on menu collapse

Tags: css, wordpress

When in the responsive/mobile view of [www.rohiniartstudio.com](https://rohiniartstudio.com/)
When I click on the menu, the menu flickers on collapsing and displays the content below the menu.
On default it was taking about 1-2s before it shows the menu items then added this code:

```
.collapsing 
{
  -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    display: none;
}
```

Can someone help me out with the flickering issue?
Please visit the site and let me know?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us in your question. You are expected to have made a good attempt to fix the problem and your question should include what you have tried to solve and *all* of your relevant code (and *only* the relevant code) in a [**minimal**, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the # value from the data-target property

Set as data-target="site-navigation".

Comment: Hey, where do I edit it from. I was successful doing it from inspection. How to I change it permanently?

Comment: How do I remove this #?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `display` property when you want to make an animation with transition. The element and all the positions should be countable by CSS.
Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38772750/9218664

If you want to make an animation on the mobile accordion menu you should use `max-height` property without `display`.

You can see how it happens here; https://codepen.io/volcanioo/pen/LYGaJdV

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please help me, how do I fix this issue?
I'm new to this. I haven't a clue what to do.