# Javascript : change 'display' and 'left' + toggle class

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, display

There are two things I want to do when clicking on a menu button. First, I want the bars to change to a cross, that's already done with `x.classList.toggle("change");` but what doesn't work is the `#navi` div that is supposed to slide right and display.

Here is what I tried : (don't mind the `#mainicons`, `#description` etc..

```js
function sidebarFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
  ('#navi').style.left = "80px";
  ('#navi').style.display = "inline";
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#navi").click(function(){
$("#navi .fa-chevron-down").toggleClass("rtoate180");
$("#navigation").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
  #more-bars{
    position:fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:35px;
    height:25px;
    left: 18px;
    top: 20px;
  }

  .bar1,
  .bar2,
  .bar3 {
    position: relative;
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    margin-top:6px;
    background-color: #843b62;
    transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  }

  .change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  }
  
    #more-bars:hover .bar1, #more-bars:hover .bar2,#more-bars:hover .bar3{
        background-color: #f67e7d
  }
  /* Main icons */

  #mainicons {
      z-index:1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 250px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #mainicons>a {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  #mainicons i {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #f67e7d;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
  }

  #mainicons i:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 7px 0px 0px 0px #f67e7d;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 7px 0px 0px 0px #f67e7d;
    box-shadow: inset 7px 0px 0px 0px #f67e7d;
    color: #f67e7d;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
  }

  /*------ SIDEBAR -----*/

  #sidebar {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    top: 0px;
  }

  /*------ Narrow sidebar -----*/

  #sidebar1 {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height: 200px;
  }

  /* Blog title */

  #blogtitle {
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 8px;
    color: #843b62;
    width: 70px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  }
  
  #blogname {
    margin-top:-30px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 8px;
    color: #843b62;
    width: 70px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left:-70px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }


  #avatar:hover ~ #blogtitle {
    -ms-transform: translate(-70px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-70px);
    transform: translate(-70px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;

  }
  #avatar:hover ~ #blogname{
    -ms-transform: translate(70px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(70px);
    transform: translate(70px);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  }
  /* Avatar */

  #avatar {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index:10;
  }

  #avatar img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
  }

  #avatar img:hover {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  /* Description */

  #description {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 80px;
    top:20px;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity:0.5;
  }
  
  #description:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 18px 18px 18px 0;
border-color: transparent #fff;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
left: -18px;
top: 85px;
}

#avatar>img:hover + #description{
    opacity:0.75;
    margin-left:110px;
}
  
  /* Search box */

  #search {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000000;
    background: #fff;
  }

  /* Navigation */

  #navi {
    cursor: pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: 40px;
    width: 170px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000000;
    background: #f67e7d;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    display:none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }

  #navi i {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 77px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #000000!important;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  #navi .fa-chevron-down {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
  }

  .rtoate180 {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  #navigation {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    background: #f67e7d;
  }

#navigation a {
    display: inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#navigationin span {
    color: #ffb997;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
  }

  #navigationin a:hover i {
-webkit-transform : rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform : rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform : rotate(360deg);
-o-transform : rotate(360deg);
transform : rotate(360deg);
    color: #fff!important;
  }
  
  #navigationin a:hover span{
      color:#fff;
  }
  
#navigation i {
    display: block;
    color: #ffb997!important;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px 10px -10px 10px;
    padding:5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="mainicons">
<a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
<a href="/ask"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></a>
<a href="/submit"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
<a href="/about"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></a>


</div>
<!--End mainicons-->

<div id="sidebar">

<div id="sidebar1">
<div id="more-bars" onclick="sidebarFunction(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="avatar"><img src="{image:Avatar}"></div>

<div id="description">
{Description}</div>
<div id="blogtitle">@actorsblog</div>
<div id="blogname">{BlogTitle}</div>

<div id="navi"> NAVIGATION <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
 
<!--Navigation-->
<div id="navigation">
 
<div id="navigationin">
<center>
<a href="{text:Link One Url}"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i><span>{text:Link One Title}</span></a>  
<a href="{text:Link Two Url}"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i><span>{text:Link Two Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Nine Url}"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i><span>{text:Link Nine Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Three Url}"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><span>{text:Link Three Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Four Url}"><i class="fa fa-film"></i><span>{text:Link Four Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Eight Url}"><i class="fa fa-link"></i><span>{text:Link Eight Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Five Url}"><i class="fa fa-file-video-o"></i><span>{text:Link Five Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Six Url}"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i><span>{text:Link Six Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Seven Url}"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i><span>{text:Link Seven Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Twitter url}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i><span>twitter</span></a>
<a href="{text:Instagram url} target="_blank""><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span>instagram</span></a>
<a href="{text:Youtube url}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i><span>youtube</span></a>
</center>
</div>
<!--End navigationin-->
 
</div>
<!--End Navigation-->


</div>
<!--End Sidebar1-->
```

Thanks:)

Comment: `('#navi').style.left = "80px";
  ('#navi').style.display = "inline";` is not valid 
Use like this `$('#navi').css({
    'left ' : "80px",
    'display' : 'inline'
  });`

Comment: toggleClass("rtoate180") has a typo

Comment: Thank you @XYZ, this worked! Do you know a way to make it work the other way round please? :)

Comment: no @Gerard it was meant to be like this actually ^^ it's like that on the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selecting an element using id you have to write it like  `document.getElementById('navi')` 
or   if using jquery use `$('#navi')` .For sliding right to work use opacity instead of display none.For details you can check  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103006/css3-transition-doesnt-work-with-display-property)

Instead of changing the style you can toggle a class and achieve the desired effect

Check this sample

```js
function sidebarFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
 
  document.getElementById('navi').classList.toggle('show')
  
 /* .opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById('navi').style.left = "80px";
   document.getElementById('navi').style.height = "30px";*/
 
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#navi").click(function(){
$("#navi .fa-chevron-down").toggleClass("rtoate180");
$("#navigation").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
#more-bars{
    position:fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:35px;
    height:25px;
    left: 18px;
    top: 20px;
  }

  .bar1,
  .bar2,
  .bar3 {
    position: relative;
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    margin-top:6px;
    background-color: #843b62;
    transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  }

  .change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  }
  
    #more-bars:hover .bar1, #more-bars:hover .bar2,#more-bars:hover .bar3{
        background-color: #f67e7d
  }
  /* Main icons */

  #mainicons {
      z-index:1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 250px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #mainicons>a {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  #mainicons i {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #f67e7d;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
  }

  #mainicons i:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 7px 0px 0px 0px #f67e7d;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 7px 0px 0px 0px #f67e7d;
    box-shadow: inset 7px 0px 0px 0px #f67e7d;
    color: #f67e7d;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
  }

  /*------ SIDEBAR -----*/

  #sidebar {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    top: 0px;
  }

  /*------ Narrow sidebar -----*/

  #sidebar1 {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height: 200px;
  }

  /* Blog title */

  #blogtitle {
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 8px;
    color: #843b62;
    width: 70px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  }
  
  #blogname {
    margin-top:-30px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 8px;
    color: #843b62;
    width: 70px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left:-70px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }


  #avatar:hover ~ #blogtitle {
    -ms-transform: translate(-70px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-70px);
    transform: translate(-70px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;

  }
  #avatar:hover ~ #blogname{
    -ms-transform: translate(70px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(70px);
    transform: translate(70px);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  }
  /* Avatar */

  #avatar {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index:10;
  }

  #avatar img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
  }

  #avatar img:hover {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  /* Description */

  #description {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 80px;
    top:20px;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity:0.5;
  }
  
  #description:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 18px 18px 18px 0;
border-color: transparent #fff;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
left: -18px;
top: 85px;
}

#avatar>img:hover + #description{
    opacity:0.75;
    margin-left:110px;
}
  
  /* Search box */

  #search {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000000;
    background: #fff;
  }

  /* Navigation */

  #navi {
    cursor: pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: 40px;
    width: 170px;
    height: 0px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000000;
    background: #f67e7d;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
   /*display:none;*/
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: left  0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: left  0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: left  0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: left  0.5s ease;
    transition: left  0.5s ease;
  }

  #navi i {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 77px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #000000!important;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  #navi .fa-chevron-down {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
  }

  .rtoate180 {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  #navigation {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    background: #f67e7d;
  }

#navigation a {
    display: inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#navigationin span {
    color: #ffb997;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
  }

  #navigationin a:hover i {
-webkit-transform : rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform : rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform : rotate(360deg);
-o-transform : rotate(360deg);
transform : rotate(360deg);
    color: #fff!important;
  }
  
  #navigationin a:hover span{
      color:#fff;
  }
  
#navigation i {
    display: block;
    color: #ffb997!important;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px 10px -10px 10px;
    padding:5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  #navi.show{
    opacity:1;
    height:30px;
    left:80px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="mainicons">
<a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
<a href="/ask"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></a>
<a href="/submit"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
<a href="/about"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></a>


</div>
<!--End mainicons-->

<div id="sidebar">

<div id="sidebar1">
<div id="more-bars" onclick="sidebarFunction(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="avatar"><img src="{image:Avatar}"></div>

<div id="description">
{Description}</div>
<div id="blogtitle">@actorsblog</div>
<div id="blogname">{BlogTitle}</div>

<div id="navi"> NAVIGATION <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
 
<!--Navigation-->
<div id="navigation">
 
<div id="navigationin">
<center>
<a href="{text:Link One Url}"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i><span>{text:Link One Title}</span></a>  
<a href="{text:Link Two Url}"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i><span>{text:Link Two Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Nine Url}"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i><span>{text:Link Nine Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Three Url}"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><span>{text:Link Three Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Four Url}"><i class="fa fa-film"></i><span>{text:Link Four Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Eight Url}"><i class="fa fa-link"></i><span>{text:Link Eight Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Five Url}"><i class="fa fa-file-video-o"></i><span>{text:Link Five Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Six Url}"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i><span>{text:Link Six Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Link Seven Url}"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i><span>{text:Link Seven Title}</span></a>
<a href="{text:Twitter url}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i><span>twitter</span></a>
<a href="{text:Instagram url} target="_blank""><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span>instagram</span></a>
<a href="{text:Youtube url}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i><span>youtube</span></a>
</center>
</div>
<!--End navigationin-->
 
</div>
<!--End Navigation-->


</div>
<!--End Sidebar1-->
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! I wanted to use display because if I click next to the bars when opacity is 0 it can still toggle the function. But if I use display it won't! Also I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I also needed it to work the other way round.. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Thank you that works great! But for the opacity there is still the problem that when you click on the right of the bars even when the navigation doesn't appear it drops the navigationin down. Display can't have a transition?

Comment: @MaëlleJumel now i have set the height to zero to avoid the click check now

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much, can I bother you one last time please?^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146443/discussion-between-xyz-and-maelle-jumel).