# Make a div appear smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a chat bubble where the user clicks on the bubble, a message will appear. The codes I used are as the following:

```js
document.getElementById("feedback_button").onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById("chat_bubble").classList.toggle("displayNone");
  if ($('#button_icon').hasClass("fa-envelope")) {
    $('#button_icon').addClass('fa-close');
    $('#button_icon').removeClass('fa-envelope');
  } else {
    $('#button_icon').removeClass('fa-close');
    $('#button_icon').addClass('fa-envelope');
  }
}
```

```css
.ChatBubble {
  background-color:red;
  height: 300px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out ;
}

.feedbackButton {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 26px !important;
  color: black !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 27px;
  -moz-border-radius: 27px;
  border-radius: 28px; 
  background-color:#424240;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out ;
}

.buttonIcon {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 13px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out ;
}

.displayNone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="chat_bubble" class="ChatBubble displayNone">Hello</div>
  <a id="feedback_button" class="feedbackButton"><i id="button_icon" class="buttonIcon fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
```

I am trying to add an animation such that the red "hello" message appears and disappears smoothly (with a transition of 0.5s) when the bubble is clicked. I am also trying to add the same smooth transition when the chat bubble switches from the envelope icon to the x icon.

I tried with   `transition-duration: 0.5s; transition-timing-function: ease-in-out ;` I have also tried `transition: 0.5s' They seem to not help at all. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot mix the style `display` with `transition`! And at the same time you have to hide the `ChatBubble` div at all, so `opacity` alone isn't enough because you still can click on the div (if there's a content in in, like a button, action will be taken if you clicked on it!), so we have to add `visibility` style to make sure it's 100% hidden.
A function that gives us an alert when we click in the `ChatBubble` div is added to the code for testing.

```js
document.getElementById("feedback_button").onclick = () => {
    document.getElementById("chat_bubble").classList.toggle("displayNone");
      if ($('#button_icon').hasClass("fa-envelope")) {
      $('#button_icon').addClass('fa-close');
      $('#button_icon').removeClass('fa-envelope');
    } 
    else {
      $('#button_icon').removeClass('fa-close');
      $('#button_icon').addClass('fa-envelope');
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementById("chat_bubble").onclick = () => {
console.log("Clicked on ChatBubble div"); 
  }
```

```css
.ChatBubble {
    background-color:red;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    visibility: visible;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .feedbackButton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 26px !important;
    color: black !important;
    text-align: center;
    width: 54px;
    height: 54px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 27px;
    -moz-border-radius: 27px;
    border-radius: 28px; 
    background-color:#424240;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .buttonIcon {
    color: white;
    padding-top: 13px;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out ;
  }
  
  .displayNone {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <div id="chat_bubble" class="ChatBubble displayNone">Hello</div>
        <a id="feedback_button" class="feedbackButton"><i id="button_icon" class="buttonIcon fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use transition on `display: none` attribute, it can be done by changing `opacity` property.

This [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22103238) will explain more about that.

```js
document.getElementById("feedback_button").onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById("chat_bubble").classList.toggle("displayNone");
  setTimeout(() => {
    $("#chat_bubble").css("display", $("#chat_bubble").hasClass("displayNone") ? "none" : "block");
  }, 500);
  
  if ($('#button_icon').hasClass("fa-envelope")) {
    $('#button_icon').addClass('fa-close');
    $('#button_icon').removeClass('fa-envelope');
  } else {
    $('#button_icon').removeClass('fa-close');
    $('#button_icon').addClass('fa-envelope');
  }
}
```

```css
.ChatBubble {
  background-color:red;
  height: 300px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out ;
}

.feedbackButton {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 26px !important;
  color: black !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 27px;
  -moz-border-radius: 27px;
  border-radius: 28px; 
  background-color:#424240;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out ;
}

.buttonIcon {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 13px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out ;
}

.displayNone {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="chat_bubble" class="ChatBubble displayNone">Hello</div>
  <a id="feedback_button" class="feedbackButton"><i id="button_icon" class="buttonIcon fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
```

Comment: Opacity alone isn't enough! you can still click on `ChatBubble` div

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can hide `ChatBubble` after the animation finished using `setTimeOut` function as the above snippet. @HakunaMatata

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the `display: none` , you can make it `opacity: 0` and change it to `opacity: 1` and add other animatable properties the same way.